# how to fix the error with CommonMapleVersion 64EXP_X?

Tags: windows, windows-7, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64, 32-bit

I am using Desktop Binder Software for my project.
it throws an error 
Could not find the required key for the initialization file : CommonMapleVersion 64EXP_X

Thanks :)

Comment: Someone answer please. Am having the same issue